# Separating dependent clauses and introductory phrases with commas in compound and complex-compound sentences

Tags: punctuation

I know that you are supposed to separate dependent clauses and introductory phrases with a comma if they start the sentence. Examples:

1. If you are ill, you ought to see a doctor. (dependent clause)
2. After the adjustment for inflation, real wages have decreased while corporate profits have grown. (introductory phrase)

Reference: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/

However, the above reference does not give examples of punctuating compound and complex-compound sentences that include dependent clauses and introductory phrases in the second part of the sentence.

Example of such a sentence with original punctuation kept (I took it from Wiktionary — an example of usage for word *particular* in sixth definition):

> He is very particular about his food and if it isn't cooked to
>   perfection he will send it back.

I think that there should be a comma after the word *food*, but that is not my question.

My question is if there should be a comma after the word *perfection*.

Similarly, sould there be a comma after an introductory phrase which comes after the first indepedent clause but before the second indepedent clause? (Although it is probably considered to be a part of that second independent clause.)

[independent clause], + coordinating conjunction + [introductiory phrase] + [independent clause].

Comma or no comma after an introductory phrase in the above structure?

Comment: @Rathony The sentence is fine as it is semantically. I'm only curious about punctuation.

Comment: @Rathony I do. BTW, you do not separate *if*-clause with a comma if it follows the independent clause. Is English your L1?

Comment: @Rathony According to your suggestion in your first comment, the sentence should be written as follows: "He is very particular about his food, if it isn't cooked to perfection, and he will send it back." Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: The question could be more complicated. Let's just write an entire grammar book, why don't we?

Comment: He is very particular about his food and, if it isn't cooked to perfection, he will send it back. There is no need to put a comma after food. The point is to set off the dependent clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should be governed by your manual of style, either the one you've chosen or the one thrust upon you.  I prefer *The Chicago Manual of Style*, but whichever one you choose realize that the there will always be allowance for the author's necessarily subjective judgment.

*CMS* notes that when it comes to punctuation, form follows function, and that said function has three components: to clarify meaning, to aid the reader, and to contribute to style.  There are two schools of thought -- *close* punctuation (which supplies the marks to follow the syntax as much as possible) an *open* punctuation (which supplies the marks only in those cases of possible "misreading.")

Close style will always recommend and open style will usually concur that coordinated independent clauses be separated by a comma unless the the clauses are very short:

> George washed and Martha dried.

In the given example, a middle-of-the-road style will thus recommend that the sentence have a comma preceding *and* and following the dependent clause:

> He is very particular about his food, and if it isn't cooked to
>   perfection, he will send it back.

Close style will bracket the dependent clause with commas:

> He is very particular about his food, and, if it isn't cooked to
>   perfection, he will send it back.

This looks choppy, and even in 1982 when the 13th edition of the *CMS* was recopyrighted, this style is noted as somewhat out of favor.

A strong open style will omit the commas in the second clause or even omit all the commas on the grounds that a markless sentence won't lead readers into misparsings.

Comment: And even with all that explanation, I would omit the comma after the first sentence in the compound sentence, i.e., after food.

Comment: @Lambie Apparently not all.